# Using Angular to display d3.js network graph data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I created an angular app with a D3 network graph that displays the data properties of each node if clicked. I expect the view to be updated, as each click changes the properties of the $scope object that's interpolated on the html file. Below is my code. The problem is that when the logic is wrapped inside the $scope.getArtist function, the view is not updated, even when I call $scope.apply inside of the click event "node.on(....)". I know the $scope is being updated because when I console.log it, it displays the correct properties, but the view is never updated. When I place the logic outside of the "$scope.getArtist function, and instead just run everything as soon as the page loads, it works. Anyone have an idea what might be going on?

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', "$sce", function($scope,  $http, $sce) {
$scope.query = {};

$scope.getArtist = function() {
    var artistQ = $scope.query.artist.split(" ").join("-");
    console.log(artistQ);
    $http.post('/home', {artist: "artistQ"}).then(function(allNodes){

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
                .attr("stroke", "grey")
                .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return 2; });

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("id", function(d){return d.level})
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
                .attr("r", function(d){
                    if(d.samplesCollection){return 5;} 
                    else {return 3.5;}
                })
                .on("mouseenter", function(d){
                    d3.selectAll("#" + d.level)
                        .attr("stroke", "red")

                    d3.selectAll("#" + "text" + d.level)
                        .style("visibility", "visible")
                })
                .on("mouseleave", function(d){
                    d3.selectAll("#" + d.level)
                        .attr("stroke", "null")

                    d3.selectAll("#" + "text" + d.level)
                        .style("visibility", "hidden")
                })
                .style("fill", function(d) { return "gold"; })
                .call(force.drag);

            ***node.on("click", function(d) {
                var youtubeURL = d.songLink;
                console.log(youtubeURL);
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    console.log("im applying!")
                    $scope.imgLink = d.imgLink;
                    $scope.songName = d.songName;
                    $scope.artistName = d.artistName;
                    $scope.album = d.album;
                    $scope.year = d.year;
                    $scope.sampleElement = d.sampleElement;
                    $scope.songLink = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(youtubeURL);
                    $scope.recLabel = d.recLabel;
                    $scope.genre = d.genre;
                    console.log("aNode", $scope);
                })
            })***


    }, function(error){
        if(error) return error
    })
}



}]);
```

P.S. some of the code was omitted for brevity, and don't have anything to do with the view not updating.

Comment: What triggers the $scope.getArtist  to run?

Comment: It's triggered by clicking a search button that makes a request to my server to dynamically change the data I'm using for the d3

Comment: are you using ng-click?

Comment: Yeah, it's an ng-click